# How do I update a MongoDB document but exclude a specific field?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I am creating a web API. I need something like this:
When I updating a document at mongodb, I do not want to update a field (createdAt). I know that  I can get a old value of that field and manuelly and then put it updated object but it requires one more unnecessarry request to db. I do not want this. My method is here:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(Customer updatedCustomer)
    {
        var result = await _mongoService.Customers.ReplaceOneAsync(c => c.Id == updatedCustomer.Id, updatedCustomer);
        return result.IsModifiedCountAvailable && result.ModifiedCount>0;
    }
```

Is there any way to exclude one property of my Customer class (createdAt) and left it same everytime. BTW please do not recomend that set all properties update one by one by using "Set" method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way other than to set the properties one by one, but researching the following may be helpful or suggestive of something new.

In Mongodb you can use some decoration to do like [BsonIgnore] but it will ignore it every time

One alternative would be to load the document you wish to modify, followed by calling BsonDocument.Merge with overwriteExistingElements set to true in order to merge your changes.